# What's the easiest way to update album art?

Tags: music, album-art

I don't have the album art for most of my music, and I don't have time to go find and download images for all of my album.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use album art?  Personally, I never look at it anyway, and it saves some space on your mp3 player (sure, not much, but over 20,000 songs it adds up.

Comment: Well that is a good idea for the mp3 player, but I'm more interested in having it for my Media Center.

Comment: @Sean, you don't have to embed album art into your music files to use album art. I just put an image in the album's directory.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it's the easiest way, but I use [Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com).  It goes to Amazon (you choose which nationality) and auto-tags what it finds.  Just click on the album and hit Ctrl+L.

My Classical music is the most problematic, but I find amazon.ca pretty good track listings.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Tag & Rename](http://softpointer.com/tr.htm). It has built-in Amazon lookup that will download cover art and save it to folder.jpg or directly in the music files as part of the ID3V2 tag.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Album Art Downloader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/album-art/). It's open source and written in .Net 3.5. To use it you simply point it at a directory and it will search for cover art for all albums within from a variety of sources.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I use [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/download.html) for Windows XP. It links to Amazon and Discogs for the album art.

Answer (score 1):

I would checkout Songbird, with the add-on of [Album Art Manager](http://addons.songbirdnest.com/addon/102). 
Songbird is an Open Source project, and has feature rich media control and organization.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/), this functionality is built in. :)

([If you are using Windows](http://windows.kde.org/))

Answer (score 1):

I use [TagScanner](http://www.xdlab.ru/en/), it does all the job, from find the artwork and update de ID3 stuff to renaming the files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use [TuneUp](http://www.tuneupmedia.com). It's paid for, but it can get album art and fix all the metadata for your library, super-simple.