# How to add album art to mp3 using vlc media player in ubuntu?

Tags: mp3, album-art

I want to add **Album art** to any mp3 song. But I don't know how to do it.My system(Ubuntu11.04)  has  **VLC media player**, **UMPlayer**, **Bashee media player**, **Movie player**. How can I add **Album art** to  mp3 file using  at least any one among those media player ?

A screenshot is given below:

[image]

Comment: So you want to edit a media file using a media _player_?  Probably not going to happen, you need a media _editor_ of some kind. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to update album art?](http://superuser.com/questions/14602/whats-the-easiest-way-to-update-album-art) also check out [Programs to automatically download album covers and insert them in to ID3 tags?](http://superuser.com/questions/263716/programs-to-automatically-download-album-covers-and-insert-them-in-to-id3-tags)

Comment: Over on AskUbuntu.com: [Need a MP3 ID3 tagger, and cover fetcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16036/need-a-mp3-id3-tagger-and-cover-fetcher)